# h5dump file.h5 h5dump eorror: unable to open file file.h5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, hdf5, cgns

When I run one of my .h5 file it opens just fine but when i try to create another file (had a .cgns file and used cgnsconvert (cgnsconvert -f file.cgns file.h5 which returns: converting HDF5 file file.cgns to ADF file file.h5) to create a .h5 file) it says it cant open the file. Any idea to why that would happen? I tried h5dump -pH file.h5, h5dump -pBH file.h5,h5dump -H file.h5, h5debug file.h5 and all return "unable/cannot open file"

Comment: Looks like `cgnsconvert ` didn't create a valid HDF5 file. Have you tried adding the `-h` option to force conversion to HDF5?

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you for responding and yes I did(cgnsconvert -h file.cgns file.h5) but it returns "input and output formats the same: use -f to force write"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured out what I did wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).